# SQL Case statement with unusual logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table:

Q.ID  Name
1   a
2   b
3   c
2   d
```

Now, If I pass value 1, output should be `1 a`

If I pass value 3, output should be `3 c`

If I pass value 4, I should get whole table

```
WHERE (@SearchTerm IS NULL OR qs.LongLabel LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%' ESCAPE '\' or oe.ANS LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%' ESCAPE '\')
    AND qs.LangID = @LangId AND 
    (@VarName IS NULL OR QNAME LIKE '%' + @VarName + '%' ) AND
(QuestionnaireID = 
        CASE @QuestionnaireType
            WHEN '4' THEN  @QuestionnaireType In('1','2','3')
            ELSE @QuestionnaireType END)
```

`QuestionnaireID` is the column name

Comment: can you try i posted answer

Comment: Column expressions are scalar.  You cannot return either a tuple or a rowset from a column expression.  This also means that a column expression cannot itself change the number or rows returned.  Post you whole query and we can show you where you have to change it to do this.

Answer (score 4):

This is simpler:

```
QuestionnaireID = @QuestionnaireType 
OR  @QuestionnaireType = '4'
```

Another way would be:

```
QuestionnaireID = CASE 
                    WHEN @QuestionnaireType = '4' THEN QuestionnaireID
                    ELSE @QuestionnaireType
                  END
```

Comment: Assuming there are only three valid values, if not you need a bit more.

Comment: @Lamak, I want that if it is 4, Search for 1,2 and 3 and take all values. If it is 1 then take only 1, if 2 then only 2 and if 3 then  only rows with questionnaireId =3

Comment: @user1989 Yes, I understood your requirement, and both ways should give you that

Comment: @Laurence What do you mean?

Comment: It the table has a `QuestionaireType` of 5, then according to the requirements it should never be displayed, but you would show it if '4' were passed. However, I suspect that the only valid values are 1-3.

Comment: @Lamak no, it giving 0 rows when uestionnaireType = '4'

Comment: @user1989 Well, it shouldn't, but then again I can't be sure since I can't see your whole query

Comment: @Lamak First query is giving results but i need to verify whether results are correct or not. The 2nd is giving 0 rows.

Can u explain me what is the first query, i tried but didnt understood it

Comment: @Lamak First query is also giving incorrect results

Comment: @user1989 Sorry man, as I said, I can't help you without seeing your whole code, you can be adding other filter conditions that might change the results

Comment: @christiandev I appreciate it, but I rolled it back, because I don't really know the rest of the structure of op's query

Comment: This does not appear to answer the OPs question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Why not?

Comment: The OP appears to want to change the number of rows returned, when the value is 4, not just change 4 into some other single value.  The uncertainty of course, is over what exactly the OP is really asking...

Comment: @RBarryYoung I think that you may be confusing a `WHERE` condition (which my answer is) with a column alias (which it isn't)

Comment: In the OPs question, yes.  But it doesn't really change anything, both are scalar expressions that cannot add rows to the resultset.  Which, again, appears to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Where are you getting that he wants to add more rows?, I'm asking seriously, because to me he's clearly asking how to do a filter that when a parameter is 4 then it returns every row and when it isn't then it returns the rows where some column has the parameter value

Comment: Hmm. OK, I see how you could get that.  I'm still not sure because the OPs lagnuage is obtuse, but that's at least as possible as my interpretation.  If you can make an edit, I can rescind my downvote.

Comment: @Lamak Yes, you are perfect in understanding. But, with your answers I am unable to get it. There is no filters

Comment: @user1989 Since there is some confusion surrounding your question, maybe you should edit the original question include some sample data and then the final desired result.  This might minimize some of the guessing about what you want.

Comment: Never mind, I made a spurious edit myself, so I could rescind it.

Comment: @user1989 so, you said that there are no other filters and then edit the question to show another filter aside the one that you had described?

Comment: @LAmak, sorry for the misunderstanding. Can you tell how would it work ?

Comment: @user1989 No, sorry, because the new filter obviously changes things. You say that my answer doesn't return results and that's most likely because of the other filter. So, I don't really understand what it is that you want to happen when the parameter value is 4

Comment: @Lamak I want the full table to return when value is 4, means QuestinaireType be 1,2 and 3

Comment: @user1989 Yes, that's what you wrote on your question at first. But you have failed to explain what do you want to happen when the parameter is 4 **and the row doesn't fulfill the other filter that you have**

Answer (score 0):

TRY like this:

```
DECLARE @QuestionnaireType int =4
SELECT * FROM 
(
select * from tbl
where   
          (  @QuestionnaireType=4 and QuestionnaireType IN (1,2,3,4))
           OR QuestionnaireType=@QuestionnaireType
           )d
           where d.QuestionnaireType!=4
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf013/3)

Comment: @user1989 Updated now try

Comment: @user1989 Provided fiddle

Comment: thanks buddy. But, I am unable to understand your query and thus unable to fit it in my main query.

Comment: I again edited my query, can u pls tell how to keep your query here

Comment: @user1989 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42294/4 updated here you will get results as you said